# React-native, imagem não aparece

Tags: react-native, image

estou iniciando no react, peguei um projeto pequeno e simples, mas tem coisas que mesmo fazendo totalmente igual não está rolando, a imagem simplesmente não aparece.

Meu arquivo App.js

```
import react from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Loja from './src/telas/Loja'

export default function App() {
      return (
            <View>
                    <Loja/>
            </View>
      );
}
```

e meu arquivo Loja.js

```
import react from "react";
import {Text, View, Image} from 'react-native';
import topo from '../../assets/lojaImg/topo.png';

export default function Loja(){
        return <View>
                        <Text>antes da imagem</Text>
                                <Image source={topo}/>
                        <Text>depois da imagem</Text>
                    </View>
}
```

Estou desenvolvendo em Windows 10, com VSCode atualizados;

Minhas tentativas foram:
1- Não há erros de digitação pois usei o recurso da tecla tab para autocompletar;
2 - Já tentei trocar o tipo de arquivo de imagem, usei PNG, SVG e JPG, nada;
3 - Removi a tag para fazer um teste, as tags de texto ficaram em uma única linha;
4 - Analisando a documentação oficial, tentei usar os recursos require e uri, também sem sucesso;
5 - Inspecionei, o elemento aparece, mas com arquivos css atrelados a ele, não faço ideia como apareceu.

Ao que parece, o elemento é reconhecido, mas há uma quantidade grande de arquivos css que devem estar de alguma forma interferindo, mas não faço ideia de como retirá-los de seja onde estiverem.
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4qCV.png)
Através da ferramenta de inspeção do Chrome tentei desativar todos esses css, mas foi em vão, nada mudou.

Depois de fechar o projeto por algum tempo, voltei a inspeciona-los com a cabeça mais arejada. Acabei detectando que havia uma configuração em uma classe de estilo (aquelas que o framework passa para o navegador sozinho) que está configurado como position: absolute, quando eu o desmarquei a imagem apareceu.
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhSE6.png)
Executei alguns testes com aplicação de estilo e funcionou, gora falta saber como driblar aquele absolute.
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPrl1.png)

Será que rolaria um downgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Você apenas precisa definir um estilo a imagem, ela não aparece pq não tem atributos básicos para definir sua estrutura, como largura e altura.
Basta vc fazer isso:

de forma inline para ficar de forma mais fácil:

```
<Image source={topo} style={{height: 100, width: 100}}/>
```

Comment: ou vc pode passar os atributos height e width cirando a variável styles e definindo uma estrutura para estilização da imagem.

Answer (score -2):

Você precisa colocar os parênteses no **return** da function Loja, deixe as  e as  dentro desses parênteses assim como você fez no primeiro arquivo. E também, no import do react você precisa utilizar a primeira letra maiúscula. Assim:

```
import React from "react";
```

Comment: Agradeço a atenção, fiz como você recomendou, mas nada aconteceu.
estarei deixando o link que acabei de criar no github para que você teste o projeto, obrigado
https://github.com/Nunesnd/react-native.git